# Boot loader of linux

Tags: linux

I am in need of help.

Recently i studied about the booting sequence of Linux OS and one of my colleague mentioned that it has 2 bootloaders. Stage 1 bootloader and Stage 2 Bootloader. He also mentioned that MBR is the Stage 1 bootloader and GRUB/LILO is the stage 2 bootloader. What is the use of having 2 bootloaders, why can't we have it united as a single bootloader?

Comment: How is the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) a bootloader? A bootloader can be _stored_ in the MBR.

Comment: He mentioned me so.... 
He mentioned me that MBR is a first bootloader and GRUB/LILO is a second bootloader.

Comment: @RajanChennai - Ask what your friend means exactly.  Your using the wrong terms.  **The MBR is not a bootloader.**

Comment: Yes.  The MBR data is technically called a **bootstrapper** or "chainloader" (though that one begets confusion with the GRUB2 parameter), not a bootloader.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bootload/index.html) informative. Here is the most relevant section:

> What is a boot loader?
>
> Most simply, a boot loader loads the operating system. When your
>   machine loads its operating system, the BIOS reads the first 512 bytes
>   of your bootable media (which is known as the master boot record, or
>   MBR). You can store the boot record of only one operating system in a
>   single MBR, so a problem becomes apparent when you require multiple
>   operating systems. Hence the need for more flexible boot loaders.
>
> The master boot record itself holds two things -- either some of or
>   all of the boot loader program and the partition table (which holds
>   information regarding how the rest of the media is split up into
>   partitions). When the BIOS loads, it looks for data stored in the
>   first sector of the hard drive, the MBR; using the data stored in the
>   MBR, the BIOS activates the boot loader.
>
> Due to the very small amount of data the BIOS can access, most boot
>   loaders load in two stages. In the first stage of the boot, the BIOS
>   loads a part of the boot loader known as the initial program loader,
>   or IPL. The IPL interrogates the partition table and subsequently is
>   able to load data wherever it may exist on the various media. This
>   action is used initially to locate the second stage boot loader, which
>   holds the remainder of the loader.
>
> The second stage boot loader is the real meat of the boot loader; many
>   consider it the only real part of the boot loader. This contains the
>   more disk-intensive parts of the loader, such as user interfaces and
>   kernel loaders. These user interfaces can range from a simple command
>   line to the all-singing, all-dancing GUIs.
>
> Boot loaders are usually configured in one of two ways: either as a
>   primary boot loader or as a secondary boot loader. Primary boot
>   loaders are where the first stage of the boot loader is installed on
>   the MBR (per the previous description). Secondary boot loaders are
>   where the first stage of the boot loader is installed onto a bootable
>   partition. A separate boot loader must then be installed into the MBR
>   and configured to pass control to the secondary boot loader.